# paypal payment showing processing/pending review after paying in paypal in checkout magento

Tags: payment, paypal, payment-gateway

I am usign magento 1.7.2.0 .
I haven't edited any core files in magento and set up checkout via paypal.
after checkout it redirects to paypal and paynow option is there.
after clicking on paynow it doesn't redirect to site back.It gives back link.
And payment status shown is Payment Review or Processing.
Why it's not showing status completed?
Why payment is not successful? any idea?please help

I have set auto return in paypal account and set url of my site in site preference and also ipn return url of site in my paypal profile.

Comment: Have you tried changing what the order status is set to in System -> Config -> Payment Methods? When you look at your settings for PayPal, make sure you have the order status set to whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Check PayPal account settings. Status **Payment Review** related to enabled same option at your PayPal account (see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOtherAPIOps/).

**Processing** is the CORRECT status. Magento orders are only (or should only be) marked as complete when you have created both the invoice AND delivery note. With PayPal Standard, the order gets invoiced automatically (after all the payment has been taken) and then you do the delivery.

Please clarify PayPal Method you use

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened because the seller/buyer's paypal accounts were created with a **different currency than the order's currency**. Worth checking this before debugging for hours.

In the end it would keep saying "PAYMENT REVIEW" due to this issue while the IPN and Magento configuration was just fine.